# AWS simultaneous requests for new instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instances

For T2 instances what is the Maximum number of simultaneous instances that can be create at one time?

Could I request 90 T2 instances at once and have them available in under a hour?
Is there a Term for the number of instances being created at one time?

If there is a cap, I assume that the cap limited by the time that the instances take to be created?
example:
So If I request 90 T2 instances and it only allows 10 at once and it takes 10 mins to be created. That would be 90 mins to have 90 T2 instances running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on your account limits. I think your account will start with a limit of 20 T2 instances of each type. That's not the limit you can start at once, but the total limit you can have in your account at one time. If you had Amazon raise your account limits such that you could have say 200 T2 instances, then the limit you could start at once would be (account limit - already running instances). So if you had 10 currently running, with a limit of 200, you could start 190.

If you make a single request asking for 90 instances, as long as it is within your account limits and Amazon has available capacity to fulfill your request, all 90 will be started at once.

Comment: Looks like everyone agrees this is the answer.